# How can I convert class component into functional component when adding React library to a Website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, micro-frontend

I want to use react component in html file. It is for micro frontend. So I follow this react official doc for [Add React to a Website](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html).

The sample code is as below:

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    
    <p>
      This is the first like.
      <div class="like_button_container" data-commentid="1"></div>
    </p>

    <p>
      This is the second like.
      <div class="like_button_container" data-commentid="2"></div>
    </p>

    <p>
      This is the third like.
      <div class="like_button_container" data-commentid="text"></div>
    </p>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

    <script src="like_button.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**like_button.js**

```
"use strict";

const e = React.createElement;

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
  }

  render() {

    return e(
      "button",
      {
        onClick: () =>
          this.setState((prevState) => ({
            liked: !prevState.liked,
          })),
      },
      this.state.liked ? "Liked " + this.props.commentID : "Unliked"
    );
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll(".like_button_container").forEach((domContainer) => {
  const commentID = domContainer.dataset.commentid;
  ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton, { commentID: commentID }), domContainer);
});
```

Above code is working fine but I want to convert *like_button.js*, which is class component into functional component.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: @David In above like_button.js file, if I used class component than it's work proper, but when I write functional component, it's stop working

Comment: Then it sounds like you have specific code which is producing a specific problem.  Perhaps you could show us that code and describe in detail that problem?  Specifically what error or unexpected result you are observing vs. what you were expecting?  For tips and information on how to ask a question, please see [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `babel standalone script` to transcompile the code, and you need to include the script for `react` and `react-dom`, use these will work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.15.7/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="react-container"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
        const App = () => <div>Hello!</div>
        ReactDOM.render(
        <App />, document.getElementById('react-container'))
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Babel Standalone converts ECMAScript 2015+ into the compatible version of JavaScript for your browser, CDN usage is described in official documentation, check babel standalone section: [Babel Standalone](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-standalone.html)